# Regex to check if the user submitted price is really a valid price

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to create a regex code to match a price with or without a dollar sign $, and with or without a comma or decimal point.

The following prices should be valid.

```
$1
$5.00
$.10
$.07
$03 //this should be interpreted as $0.03 in case if you are confused
$10,000
$10,000.00

1
5.00
.10
.07
03 //this should be interpreted as $0.03 in case if you are confused
10,000
10,000.00
```

Here is my code so far:

```
preg_match('/^([1-9][0-9]*|0)(\.[0-9]{2})?$/', $price)
```

Comment: Interpreting `03` as `.03` seems like a really bad time waiting to happen.

Comment: If you've the intl extension installed you can use `NumberFormatter::parse()` method to parse formatted numbers. For further information take a look into the PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

Comment: @Alex Howansky how is this bad?

Comment: @Kyoya the intl extension is not installed.

Comment: It's bad because it's the only one of your cases where you're explicitly inserting a decimal point at a place that differs from its implicit location. Users would not expect `$03` and `$0.03` to yield the same value. What happens if I type `$03.03` or `$003`? It's very confusing.

Comment: What should not be matched? Is it batches of three that should allow commas or only upto 99k?

Comment: Someone knows how to "ping". Which suggests they know how things roll on Stack. Accepting an answer marks the question as solved.

Comment: Instead of letting your users input any garbage they want and trying to make sense of it be strict about what your application *allows* and only accept a handful of explicit formats. If it doesn't match an accepted format, throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you like this?

```
preg_match(
    '/^' .
    '\$?' . // optional dollar sign
    '[\d]*' . // any digits (0 or not does not make a difference, 03 is valid as well as .03 or 0.03)
    '(,\d{3})*?' . // a comma has to be followed by 3 digits to be valid
    '(.\d\d)?' . // the point has to be followed by 2 digits to be valid
    '$/', // the end
    $price
);
```

You have to adapt this, if you wanna force a comma after every three digits. However there are good regex if you google "regex float" (like http://www.regular-expressions.info/floatingpoint.html)

I am not sure why the "03" or "$03" is important. If you want to verify the string, okay. If you just want to convert it to a float, I would keep it simple, stupid:

```
$price = str_replace(['$', ','], '', $str);
    if ('0' === $price[0]) {
        $price = '.' . $price;
    }
    $price = (float) $price;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex -

```
^\$?(?:(?:\d+(?:,\d+)?(?:\.\d+)?)|(?:\.\d+))$
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/UzWWEC/1), which also explains it.

Note that I've added 03 and .03 as separate entries. This regex will just match them.

Answer (score -1):

I quickly spun up a function for checking if a string or int is a valid price and if not, converting it. The final output is always going to be a string with two digits after the decimal, like `1000.00`.

It removes minus/negative signs, commas, spaces, and dollar signs. The only except is when if the string contains any characters like letters that would set [`is_numeric()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php) to false.

Here is the function:

```
function convertToValidPrice($price) {
    $price = str_replace(['-', ',', '$', ' '], '', $price);
    if(!is_numeric($price)) {
        $price = null;
    } else {
        if(strpos($price, '.') !== false) {
            $dollarExplode = explode('.', $price);
            $dollar = $dollarExplode[0];
            $cents = $dollarExplode[1];
            if(strlen($cents) === 0) {
                $cents = '00';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) === 1) {
                $cents = $cents.'0';
            } elseif(strlen($cents) > 2) {
                $cents = substr($cents, 0, 2);
            }
            $price = $dollar.'.'.$cents;
        } else {
            $cents = '00';
            $price = $price.'.'.$cents;
        }
    }

    return $price;
}
```

And here is to test it:

```
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100'));          // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('-100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice(100));            // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('$100'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98'));       // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.9'));        // 100.90
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.'));         // 100.00
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,00.98'));      // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('1,000.98'));     // 1000.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('100.98829382')); // 100.98
var_dump(convertToValidPrice('abc'));          // null
```